# Can we update messages in AWS SQS FIFO Queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We can send/receive messages to/from AWS SQS Queue, But Can we update message content which is already in SQS Queue ? If possible , How ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once a message has been sent to an SQS queue (standard or FIFO), the message is immutable.  Additionally, it isn't possible to ask SQS for a specific message by its ID.

The message is essentially inaccessible until received by a consumer.

(Viewing messages in the AWS console might seem to be an exception, but it isn't -- the console acts as a consumer, receives messages, and then resets their visibility timeout so they return to the queue for subsequent redelivery.)