# Is it possible to enrich a message on an sqs queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a message I am reading off an sqs queue. If the operation I am performing succeeds I delete the message from the queue.

But if the operation fails I was thinking of enriching the message on the queue to have some extra information about the failure.

Is enriching a message on the queue (between reading and deleting) possible using sqs?

Comment: why not add a new message to the queue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we update messages in AWS SQS FIFO Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109303/can-we-update-messages-in-aws-sqs-fifo-queue)

Comment: A new message on the queue? But in that case it would just feed into my process that reads off the queue. Is there a trick around handling that? @DanielA.White. Otherwise i guess we are talking a completely different queue named something along the lines of queue-name-error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible to update/modify a message in the queue.

Each time a message is retrieved, it increments the `ApproximateReceiveCount` (the number of times a message has been received from the queue but not deleted), but otherwise the message cannot be modified.

Instead, you could store supplemental information in a database (eg DynamoDB) indexed by `MessageId`, and retrieve that information when processing a message.